# Is there any difference in threading between Linux and Windows on python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have written a program which use thread in Tkinter. It works fine when I run this program on linux, but when the same program run on Windows it doesn't work.

Problem exist when loop (which is run under thread) is ended and call function which cause to appear Toplevel window

Any suggestions??

Comment: There are always differences between Linux and Windows. But without a reproducible sample of your code showing the issue, we cannot tell you what exactly is causing your specific problem.

Comment: Linux and Windows use different scheduling algorithms (also the case with different versions of Windows).  A common issue with threading is timing - you can never predict the order things happen in.  It is likely that you should be serialising an operation using synchronisation (like Lock) and are getting away with the error on Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: So there is no solution for Windows???

Comment: As I said, more than likely you have the same bug on Linux, it is just not yet being found.  It is unlikely that it is a Windows issue but an issue with your code.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But can you help me with my code? What could I do to get it work. I released my code below.

Comment: Without going through each line, one thing I have noticed is that you are not doing a `t.join()` anywhere, so you are not waiting for the thread to complete.  In theory the main program could exit while the thread is executing.  I'm not sure if that is an issue or not without stepping through your program logic, which would take more time than I have.

Comment: ok, good point. I try to implement it.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you can't use threading with Tkinter. Or more accurately, you can only access tkinter widgets and functions from the thread that created them. If your thread is creating a window, that simply will not work on windows, and may work non-deterministically on other platforms.

Comment: hmmm... is it mean that in my case loop which at the end calls function which cause to appear window is still in a separate thread?? I thought that only loop is performed under separate thread. If it is true is there any possibility to call funcion from separate thread??

Comment: You will have to put a request on a queue, and have your main thread poll that queue and do the work. There are examples on stackoverflow. _However_, if all you're doing is counting down some time, you don't need threads at all.